# I'm scraping two different websites with beautifulSoup - how can I run it in one code?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape several company sites for job positions (I have permission). They have slightly different HTML structure so I have created several scrapers to scrape the individual websites. The output from the scrapers are the same which is the urls to the job postings.

**Issue**

I have the scrapers and they are working fine individually - however for efficiency purposes I would like to be able to run them at the same time, instead of having to run them individually. What's the easiest way to do that?

**Scraper 1**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

base = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com"
url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/1143"

req = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')
links = soup.select("a")

for link in links:
    if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
        res = requests.get(base + link.get("href")).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
        title = soup.select_one("h1.page-intro__title").get_text() if 
soup.select_one("h1.section__title") else ""
        overview = soup.select_one("p.page-intro__longDescription").get_text()
        details = soup.select_one("div.rte").get_text()
        print(title, link, details)
```

**Scraper 2**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 
"http://deloittedk.easycruit.com/_sp=136ecff9b65625bf.1504382903200&icid=top_"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
            print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)
```

Comment: You might want to look at Python's Multiprocessing - https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: To improve performance use `lxml` instead of `html.parser`.

Comment: just use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). Or if you intend to do some kind of common API based on multiple site backends, you could have a look to the [weboob scraping framework](http://weboob.org/) which is very powerful and useful when wanting to abstract multiple sites in parallel.

Comment: Thanks guys - very useful!